# Nancy/TinyIoC multiple concrete classes for single interface

Tags: nancy

We have two auth methods for different modules – `UserAuthModule` and `ServiceAuthModule`. We’ve created 2 base classes that modules derive from. We’ve interfaced the AuthProviders into `IAuthProvider`. Then we have a dependency in the constructors that should get the correct AuthProvider injected. However, we can’t find a way to tell Nancy/TinyIoC which concrete class to use. Here is the pseudo-code:

```
abstract class UserAuthModule : NancyModule
{
  public UserAuthModule(IAuthProvider authProvider) // should get the UserAuthProvider concrete class
}

abstract class ServiceAuthModule : NancyModule
{
  public ServiceAuthModule(IAuthProvider authProvider) // should get the ServiceAuthProvider concrete class
}
```

Here's an example of one of the concrete module's class declaration:

```
public class AccountModule : UserAuthModule
```

We then get stuck: how do we register 2 concrete classes for the IAuthProvider interface? We could name them, but can’t figure out how Nancy knows which class to inject when it does the constructor injection.

Inside our bootstrapper we have:

```
Container.Register<IAuthProvider, UserAuthProvider>(“UserAuth”);
Container.Register<IAuthProvider, ServiceAuthProvider>(“ServiceAuth”);
```

We could resolve the type from the container, but there's not container access within the Nancy module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is creating a unique interface for each based off of IAuthProvider out of the question?

```
interface IUserAuthProvider : IAuthProvider { }
interface IServiceAuthProvider : IAuthProvider { }
```

And then register:

```
Container.Register<IUserAuthProvider, UserAuthProvider>();
Container.Register<IServiceAuthProvider, ServiceAuthProvider>();
```

And then modify the constructors:

```
public UserAuthModule(IUserAuthProvider authProvider)
public ServiceAuthModule(IServiceAuthProvider authProvider)
```

Comment: You make life seem so simple.